# When i click on the button, I've getting an Toast "App isn't responding"

Tags: android, database

I have a problem with my app, after I click on the button which should add data (specified by user body parts) to database, and in the next layout, it should display an exercises for those body parts. Everything worked fine until I've added an another training day which is Friday (Program have to display 9 spinners - 3x Monday, 3x Wednesday, 3x Friday) When I've click on the button, that I mentioned already it  should add data to database, and change the layout, app just getting dark, and after a while it says "Gym isn't responding" How can I fix it? I think, I'm just overloaded the app. I don't know exactly which code should I post here, so I leave it without for now, please tell me guys what code should I add here

Comment: Paste your code.

Comment: Check if there are no recursive calls in your code.